# x86 LOCK question on multi-core CPUs

Tags: assembly, locking, x86, cpu, multicore

Is it true that the x86 ASM "LOCK" command prefix causes all cores to freeze while the instruction following "LOCK" is being executed?

I read this in a blog post and it doesn't make sense. I can't find anything that indicates if this is true or not.

Comment: Related: [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393850/can-num-be-atomic-for-int-num) where my answer explains more about how `lock`ed instructions execute internally.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's about locking the memory bus for that address. [The Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual - Volume 3A: System Programming Guide, Part 1](http://download.intel.com/design/processor/manuals/253668.pdf) tells us:

> 7.1.4 Effects of a LOCK Operation on Internal Processor Caches.
>
> For the Intel486 and Pentium processors, the LOCK# signal is always
>   asserted on the bus during a LOCK
>   operation, even if the area of memory
>   being locked is cached in the
>   processor.
>
> For the P6 and more recent processor
>   families, *if the area of memory being
>   locked during a LOCK operation is
>   cached in the processor that is
>   performing the LOCK operation as
>   write-back memory and is completely
>   contained in a cache line, the
>   processor may not assert the LOCK#
>   signal on the bus*. Instead, it will
>   modify the memory location internally
>   and allow [its] cache coherency
>   mechanism to insure that the operation
>   is carried out atomically. This
>   operation is called "cache locking."
>   The cache coherency mechanism
>   automatically prevents two or more
>   processors that have the same area of
>   memory from simultaneously modifying
>   data in that area. (emphasis added)

Here we learn that the P6 and newer chips are smart enough to determine if they really have to block off the bus or can just rely on intelligent caching. I think this is a neat optimization.

I discussed this more in my blog post "[How Do Locks Lock?](http://www.moserware.com/2008/09/how-do-locks-lock.html)"

Comment: Jeff, thanks for filling in the blanks and providing references.  It's nice to see that more recent processors are somewhat smarter about locking.

Comment: Thank you, this is just the information I expect to find when googling for lock prefix :)

Answer (score 6):

No, but it may force other processors to wait while this one accesses memory.  Whether these wait states ever make a difference depend on the extent to which the processors are running off a cache.