# What happens if two theads lock a mutex concurrently?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, theory, mutex

I'm interested in how a mutex works. I understand their purpose as every website I have found explains what they do but I haven't been able to understand what happens in this case:

> There are two threads running concurrently and they try to lock the mutex at the same time.

This would not be a problem on a single core as this situation could never happen, but in a multi-core system I see this as a problem. I can't see any way to prevent concurrency problems like this but they obviously exist.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm pretty sure multi-core systems have some sort of mechanism either at the OS/Hypervisor level or in the CPU/bus management so that this can't happen.

Comment: they can't that is point of a mutex it can only be acquired once

Comment: Two threads (or 10 threads) can _try_ to lock a mutex simultaneously, but only one will succeed. And it can happen with a single core - the OS will be switching from thread to thread all the time, and it can switch away from one thread just when it is trying to lock a mutex, and switch to another thread which immediately tries to lock the same mutex, and this must work correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A mutex, when properly implemented, can never be locked concurrently. For this, you need some atomic operations (operations that are guaranteed to be the only thing happening to an object at one moment) that have useful properties.

One such operation is `xchg` (exchange) in the x86 architecture. For instance `xchg eax, [ebp]` will read the value at the address `ebp`, write the value in `eax` to the address `ebp` and then set `eax` to the read value, while guaranteeing that these actions won't be interleaved with concurrent reads and writes to that address.

Now you can implement a mutex. To lock, load `1` into `eax`, exchange `eax` with the value of the mutex and look at `eax`. If it's `1`, it was already locked, so you might want to sleep and try again later. If it's `0`, you just locked the mutex. To unlock, simply write a value of `0` to the mutex.

Please note that I'm glossing over important details here. For instance, x86's `xchg` is atomic enough for pre-emptive multitasking on a single processor. When you're sharing memory between multiple processors (e.g. in a multi-core system), it won't be enough unless you use the `lock` prefix (e.g. `lock xchg eax, [ebp]`, rather than `xchg eax, [ebp]`), which [ensures that only one processor can access that memory while the instruction is executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339141/x86-lock-question-on-multi-core-cpus/3339380#3339380).

Comment: There's `LOCK`-prefixed instructions for multi-core x86, e.g. `LOCK XCHG eax, [ebp]`.

Comment: @MarkKCowan Good point! I'll update the answer to reflect the SMP situation a bit better.

Answer (score 8):

It's not possible for 2 threads to lock a system wide Mutex, one will lock it the other will be blocked.

> The semantics of mutex/lock! ensure that only one thread can execute
>   beyond the lock call at any one time. The first thread that reaches
>   the call acquires the lock on the mutex. Any later threads will block
>   at the call to mutex/lock! until the thread that owns the lock
>   releases the lock with mutex/unlock!.

In terms of how it's possible to implement this, take a look [test-and-set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set).

> In computer science, the test-and-set instruction is an instruction
>   used to write to a memory location and return its old value as a
>   single atomic (i.e., non-interruptible) operation. If multiple
>   processes may access the same memory, and if a process is currently
>   performing a test-and-set, no other process may begin another
>   test-and-set until the first process is done. CPUs may use
>   test-and-set instructions offered by other electronic components, such
>   as dual-port RAM; CPUs may also offer a test-and-set instruction
>   themselves.
>
> The calling process obtains the lock if the old value was 0. It spins
>   writing 1 to the variable until this occurs.

Comment: Hi , is this same situation for two process also ?
I mean What happens if two processes lock a mutex concurrently?