# What does the "lock" instruction mean in x86 assembly?

Tags: c++, qt, assembly, x86

I saw some x86 assembly in Qt's source:

```
q_atomic_increment:
    movl 4(%esp), %ecx
    lock 
    incl (%ecx)
    mov $0,%eax
    setne %al
    ret

    .align 4,0x90
    .type q_atomic_increment,@function
    .size   q_atomic_increment,.-q_atomic_increment
```

1. From Googling, I knew `lock` instruction will cause CPU to lock the bus, but I don't know when CPU frees the bus?
2. About the whole above code, I don't understand how this code implements the `Add`?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3339380/856777

Comment: related: my answer on [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393850/can-num-be-atomic-for-int-num) explains atomicity on x86, and what exactly the `lock` prefix does, and what would happen without it.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

1. `LOCK` is not an instruction itself: it is an instruction prefix, which applies to the following instruction. That instruction must be something that does a read-modify-write on memory (`INC`, `XCHG`, `CMPXCHG` etc.) --- in this case it is the `incl (%ecx)` instruction which `inc`rements the `l`ong word at the address held in the `ecx` register.

   The `LOCK` prefix ensures that the CPU has exclusive ownership of the appropriate cache line for the duration of the operation, and provides certain additional ordering guarantees. This may be achieved by asserting a bus lock, but the CPU will avoid this where possible. If the bus is locked then it is only for the duration of the locked instruction.
2. This code copies the address of the variable to be incremented off the stack into the `ecx` register, then it does `lock incl (%ecx)` to atomically increment that variable by 1. The next two instructions set the `eax` register (which holds the return value from the function) to 0 if the new value of the variable is 0, and 1 otherwise. The operation is an **increment**, not an add (hence the name).

Comment: So the instuction "mov $0,%eax" seems redundant?

Comment: @gemfield: No, the `MOV` sets the all of `EAX` to zero. `SETNE` only changes the low byte. Without the `MOV`, the 3 high bytes of `EAX` would contain random leftover values from previous operations, so the return value would be incorrect.

Comment: In one of the Russia book "Assembler for DOS, Windows и Linux, 2000. Sergei Zukkov" author mentioned the following about this prefix: "In all the time of the command, provided with such a prefix, the data bus will be suspended, and if a system has a different processor, it can not access memory until the end of the command with the prefix LOCK. XCHG command automatically always performed with the memory access lock, even if the LOCK prefix is not specified. This prefix can be used only with commands ADD, ADC, AND, BTC, BTR, BTS, CMPXCHG, DEC, INC, NEG, NOT, OR, SBB, SUB, XOR, XADD and XCHG."

Comment: @bruziuz: modern CPUs are *much* more efficient: if the data for a `lock`ed instruction doesn't cross a cache line, a CPU core can just internally lock that cache line instead of blocking all loads/stores from all other cores.  See also my answer on [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393850/can-num-be-atomic-for-int-num) for more details of how this works to make it *appear* atomic to possible observers using the MESI cache-coherency protocol.

Comment: Thank you very much! Cool!  :)

Comment: See also [LOCK prefix vs MESI protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29880015) re: the MESI cache-lock part specifically, for a plain `add` vs. `lock add`.  (Cache-line-split `lock`ed operations are disastrously expensive, affecting memory access by all other cores.  So don't do that.)

Answer (score 18):

The microcode required to increment a value requires that we read in the old value first.

The Lock keyword forces the multiple micro instructions that are actually occuring to appear to operate atomically.

If you had 2 threads each trying to increment the same variable, and they both read the same original value at the same time then they both increment to the same value, and they both write out the same value.

Instead of having the variable incremented twice, which is the typical expectation, you end up  incrementing the variable once.

The lock keyword prevents this from happening.

Answer (score 15):

> From google, I knew lock instruction will cause cpu lock the bus,but I
>   don't know when cpu free the bus ?

`LOCK` is an instruction prefix, hence it only applies to the following instruction, the source doesn't make it very clear here but the real instruction is `LOCK INC`. So the Bus is locked for the increment, then unlocked

> About the whole above code, I don't understand how these code
>   implemented the Add?

They don't implement an Add, they implement an increment, along with a return indication if the old value was 0. An addition would use `LOCK XADD` (however, windows InterlockedIncrement/Decrement are also implement with `LOCK XADD`).

Comment: Thanks! Then which register stores the value of function(q_atomic_increment)'s return value ?

Comment: return values are stored in %eax

Comment: So,the code: "return q_atomic_increment(&_q_value) != 0" is to test whether %eax is not equal to zero ?

Comment: @gemfield: its zero'd, then the LSB is set via `SETNE` using the conditional flags from `INC`.

Comment: Is it whether the _old_ value was 0 or not that's returned in %eax (as the answer currently states), or the _new_ value?

Comment: @Tom it's the new value indeed.
the inc set the zero flag according to the result of the inc and not according to the sources. see: https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_140.html

Comment: Locking the bus was done with 486/Pentium. This is very inefficient because is creates a huge contention point and this reduces performance of the system (Amdahl's law). That is why they switched to locking on a cache line level in most cases. 

For more information see:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3a-part-1-manual.html Section 8.1.4

Answer (score 4):

**Minimal runnable C++ threads + LOCK inline assembly example**

main.cpp

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

std::atomic_ulong my_atomic_ulong(0);
unsigned long my_non_atomic_ulong = 0;
unsigned long my_arch_atomic_ulong = 0;
unsigned long my_arch_non_atomic_ulong = 0;
size_t niters;

void threadMain() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < niters; ++i) {
        my_atomic_ulong++;
        my_non_atomic_ulong++;
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "incq %0;"
            : "+m" (my_arch_non_atomic_ulong)
            :
            :
        );
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "lock;"
            "incq %0;"
            : "+m" (my_arch_atomic_ulong)
            :
            :
        );
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    size_t nthreads;
    if (argc > 1) {
        nthreads = std::stoull(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    } else {
        nthreads = 2;
    }
    if (argc > 2) {
        niters = std::stoull(argv[2], NULL, 0);
    } else {
        niters = 10000;
    }
    std::vector<std::thread> threads(nthreads);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nthreads; ++i)
        threads[i] = std::thread(threadMain);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nthreads; ++i)
        threads[i].join();
    assert(my_atomic_ulong.load() == nthreads * niters);
    assert(my_atomic_ulong == my_atomic_ulong.load());
    std::cout << "my_non_atomic_ulong " << my_non_atomic_ulong << std::endl;
    assert(my_arch_atomic_ulong == nthreads * niters);
    std::cout << "my_arch_non_atomic_ulong " << my_arch_non_atomic_ulong << std::endl;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/77c7df5fcded3a87aaed1de0f8d2335ba909d574/userland/cpp/atomic.cpp).

Compile and run:

```
g++ -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.cpp -pthread
./main.out 2 10000
```

Possible output:

```
my_non_atomic_ulong 15264
my_arch_non_atomic_ulong 15267
```

From this we see that the LOCK prefix made the addition atomic: without it we have race conditions on many of the adds, and the total count at the end is less than the synchronized 20000.

The LOCK prefix is used to implement:

- C++11 `std::atomic`: [What exactly is std::atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978324/what-exactly-is-stdatomic/58904448#58904448)
- C11 `atomic_int`: [How do I start threads in plain C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810/how-do-i-start-threads-in-plain-c/52453291#52453291)

See also: [What does multicore assembly language look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980999/what-does-multicore-assembly-language9-look-like/33651438#33651438)

Tested in Ubuntu 19.04 amd64.

Comment: What's the point of using `-O0`, and fencing the non-atomic increment with a full barrier (`lock inc`)?  To prove that it's still broken even in the best-case scenario?  You'd see many more lost counts if you let non-locked `inc` forward from the store buffer.

Comment: @PeterCordes `-O0`: hadn't put much thought into it, done by default for better debug, although I laster noticed that it does make it a bit easier to see the behavior i such a simple case because `-O3` optimizes loop to a single add. "and fencing the non-atomic increment with a full barrier": does LOCK also affect the non atomic variables on the above program?

Comment: `lock inc` is a full barrier, like `mfence`.  You don't have 4 separate loops, you interleave increments.  It doesn't make the other `inc` *atomic*, but it forces `inc`'s store to be globally visible before the next `inc`'s load, so yes it affects it significantly.  If you don't want `-O3` to hoist out of the loop and do `+= N`, you can use `volatile`; constraining code-gen without giving any kind of atomicity is what `volatile` is for.