# How to avoid using volatile for lockfree program?

Tags: c++, synchronization

My program is comprised of a bunch of threads happily chugging along, and the only synchronization I have is a `volatile` global `bool` that tells them if the user exited. All other communication between the threads is lockfree. These threads constantly have work to do, in a very time critical application, so I can't afford having locks between them. I recently came across a lot of information showing that `volatile` is bad for multi-threading, so I want to make my code better. I saw that `std::atomic_flag` is guaranteed lockfree, but I can't figure out how to use it for my case.

The basic setup is like this (omitting different files that the code is in):

```
// Global variable in its own .h file
extern volatile bool SystemOnline;

// Initialization in a .cpp file    
volatile bool SystemOnline = true;

// Windows message processing
while (SystemOnline)
{
    MSG msg;
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        {
            SystemOnline = false;
        }
        else if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, NULL, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
}

// Thread functions
void Thread1()
{
    while (SystemOnline)
    {
        // Do some work
    }
}

void Thread2()
{
    while (SystemOnline)
    {
        // Do some other work
    }
}

// And so on...
```

All threads are joined at the end.

Comment: `volatile` has absolutely nothing to do with thread synchronization, and doesn't in any way help prevent data races. You are looking for [`std::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic). In the code shown, you could simply make it `std::atomic<bool> SystemOnline = true;`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik volatile is used to make the while statements exit when the variable becomes false. std::atomic is not guaranteed to be lockfree and can tank the performance of all threads. As I said, I'm trying to get rid of volatile, but the replacement needs to perform just as well

Comment: No reasonable compiler will have a locking `std::atomic<bool>` or `std::atomic<int>`. If you want to be extra sure, check with `is_lock_free()`. `volatile` does not prevent data races. Your program exhibits undefined behavior; "seems to work" is merely one possible manifestation of undefined behavior.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik There's no data race here. The variable is only modified once in the entire lifetime of the program. Worst case is that the threads run for a few iterations more than needed. Can you elaborate on the undefined behavior? I will check if atomic bool is indeed lockfree

Comment: The variable is modified in one thread, and read in another - possibly concurrently, as these two operations are not synchronized. This is the definition of a [data race](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Threads_and_data_races).

Comment: @EyalK. If you want to make sure that there are no locks when you use `std::atomic<bool>`, just add a `static_assert(std::atomic<bool>::is_always_lock_free)` in your code or before C++17, check that the macro `ATOMIC_BOOL_LOCK_FREE` expands to `2`. If `std::atomic<bool>` is not lock free, then there is probably a good hardware-level reason for that indicating that (fully) atomicity may not be possible without lock.

Comment: @EyalK. - as others have pointed out `volatile` doesn't do what you think it does any more reliably.  Back in the days of single-core machines and i386, you could reasonably use volatile to enable atomic assignments. But once multi-processing and multi-core became a thing, all bets are off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's fix the bigger performance problem first.  Your main Win32 thread is spinning without waiting.  That's going to negate any perceived performance difference between a lockless bool and an std::atomic.

You'll burn an entire core just invoking PeekMessage redundantly on an empty queue.  So instead of this:

```
while (SystemOnline)
{
    MSG msg;
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        {
            SystemOnline = false;
        }
        else if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, NULL, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Let's do the following which is **exactly equivalent** to what you have above except that `GetMessage` will block until an incoming message arrives. And GetMessage returns FALSE when a WM_QUIT message is dequeued.

```
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, NULL, &msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
SystemOnline = false;
```

And as other have pointed out, the conversion from a global bool to an atomic is pretty simple:

Just change this global:

```
// Global variable in its own .h file
extern volatile bool SystemOnline;

// Initialization in a .cpp file    
volatile bool SystemOnline = true;
```

To this:

```
// Global variable in its own .h file
#include <atomic>
extern std::atomic<bool> SystemOnline;

// Initialization in a .cpp file    
std::atomic<bool> SystemOnline(true);
```

You can also use `std::atomic_bool` - it's a typedef for `std::atomic<bool>`

And that's all you have to do.  You don't even have to change your thread code since the `()` operator for this type just invokes the `load()` method on the object.  Similarly, the `= false` assignment at the end of the main thread loop is the same as invoking `SystemOnline.store(false)`.

As others have pointed out, there really isn't much of a performance penalty for using the atomic.  On x86, it maps to the [LOCK opcode prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891067/what-does-the-lock-instruction-mean-in-x86-assembly).

Comment: GetMessage() takes only 4 arguments, PM_REMOVE needs to not be there, but otherwise it works.