# Is the c++ operator |= atomic with a multicore processor?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing, atomic

I am currently in debate with another developer who assures me that the following c++ statement is atomic:

```
x |= 0x1; // x is shared by multiple threads
```

Compiled with VC++11 in release mode this generates the following assemby:

```
01121270  or          dword ptr ds:[1124430h],1
```

The other developer says that the bit operations are atomic and therefore thread safe. My experience with an intel i7 processor says otherwise.

I thought that with a multicore processor, any shared memory write is unsafe because of the individual processor caches. But having done more research it seems as though the x86 processors provide some guarantees in relation to the order of memory operations between processors/cores which suggest that it *should* be safe... again, this doesn't seem to be the case in my experience.

Since I don't have authoritative knowledge of these kinds of things it's difficult for me to put my case or even be confident that I'm right.

Comment: It's just platform-dependent, isn't it? I think you should specify your platform.

Comment: Some compilers may generate thread-safe code on some architectures, but there's no guarantee. There's also no disadvantage to using `std::atomic<int>`, which has an `operator|=` that is guranteed to be atomic, so you should do that.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that a `lock` instruction prefix is required on x86 architectures to ensure atomicity in the case of multiple processors/cores. I.e. it would have to be `lock or dword ptr ds:[11224430h],1`. But I don't have a reference handy. What does it compile to if you `use std::atomic<int>`?

Comment: See for eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339141/x86-lock-question-on-multi-core-cpus

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm referring to the x86 platform

Comment: using std::atomic< uint32_t> does indeed add 'lock' to the or instruction. The downside to std::atomic is that it's c++11 only.

Comment: @RobertSmith In pre-11, there's always [Boost.Atomic](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/atomic.html).

Comment: Yes, but boost is unavailable in my company and the specific issue is in a third party library anyway and I presume that the developer would prefer not to introduce a dependency on boost or c++11.

Comment: That instruction is an unlocked read-modify-write instruction. So it didn't even happen to produce an atomic operation on VC++11 in release mode. Nothing prevents another core from stealing the cache line during the modify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's definitely not guaranteed to be atomic. Whether it's implemented using an uniterruptible instruction (sequence) or not is up to the compiler and platform. But from the point of view of the standard, it's not atomic; so if one thread perfroms `x |= 0x1;` and another thread accesses `x` without a synchronisation point in between, it's Undefined Behaviour (a data race).

Supporting quotes from C++11:

1.10/5:

> The library defines a number of atomic operations (Clause 29) and operations on mutexes (Clause 30)
>   that are specially identified as synchronization operations. ...

Clause 29 introduces `std::atomic` and related functions. It does not specify fundamental types as atomic.

1.10/21:

> The execution of a program contains a *data race* if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads,
>   at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in
>   undefined behavior. ...

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling this was the case but not the confidence to assert it.

Comment: @RobertSmith For the record, "coflicting actions" and "happens before" are also defined exactly in 1.10, but I didn't want to copy half the chapter.